# Memory requirements for Stanford NER retraining

Tags: java, jvm, stanford-nlp

I am retraining the Stanford NER model on my own training data for extracting organizations. But, whether I use a 4GB RAM machine or an 8GB RAM machine, I get the same Java heap space error.

Could anyone tell what is the general configuration of machines on which we can retrain the models without getting these memory issues?

I used the following command :

```
 java -mx4g -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop newdata_retrain.prop
```

I am working with training data (multiple files - each file has about 15000 lines in the following format) - one word and its category on each line

She     O
is      O
working     O
at     O
Microsoft      ORGANIZATION

Is there anything else we could do to make these models run reliably ? I did try with reducing the number of classes in my training data. But that is impacting the accuracy of extraction. For example, some locations or other entities are getting classified as organization names. Can we reduce specific number of classes without impact on accuracy ?

One data I am using is the Alan Ritter twitter nlp data : https://github.com/aritter/twitter_nlp/tree/master/data/annotated/ner.txt

The properties file looks like this:

```
#location of the training file
trainFile = ner.txt
#location where you would like to save (serialize to) your
#classifier; adding .gz at the end automatically gzips the file,
#making it faster and smaller
serializeTo = ner-model-twitter.ser.gz

#structure of your training file; this tells the classifier
#that the word is in column 0 and the correct answer is in
#column 1
map = word=0,answer=1

#these are the features we'd like to train with
#some are discussed below, the rest can be
#understood by looking at NERFeatureFactory
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
#no ngrams will be included that do not contain either the
#beginning or end of the word
noMidNGrams=true
useDisjunctive=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=1
#the next 4 deal with word shape features
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
saveFeatureIndexToDisk = true
```

The error I am getting : the stacktrace is this :

```
CRFClassifier invoked on Mon Dec 01 02:55:22 UTC 2014 with arguments:
   -prop twitter_retrain.prop
usePrevSequences=true
useClassFeature=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useSequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
saveFeatureIndexToDisk=true
useTypeySequences=true
useDisjunctive=true
noMidNGrams=true
serializeTo=ner-model-twitter.ser.gz
maxNGramLeng=6
useNGrams=true
usePrev=true
useNext=true
maxLeft=1
trainFile=ner.txt
map=word=0,answer=1
useWord=true
useTypeSeqs=true
[1000][2000]numFeatures = 215032
setting nodeFeatureIndicesMap, size=149877
setting edgeFeatureIndicesMap, size=65155
Time to convert docs to feature indices: 4.4 seconds
numClasses: 21 [0=O,1=B-facility,2=I-facility,3=B-other,4=I-other,5=B-company,6=B-person,7=B-tvshow,8=B-product,9=B-sportsteam,10=I-person,11=B-geo-loc,12=B-movie,13=I-movie,14=I-tvshow,15=I-company,16=B-musicartist,17=I-musicartist,18=I-geo-loc,19=I-product,20=I-sportsteam]
numDocuments: 2394
numDatums: 46469
numFeatures: 215032
Time to convert docs to data/labels: 2.5 seconds
Writing feature index to temporary file.
numWeights: 31880772
QNMinimizer called on double function of 31880772 variables, using M = 25.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.QNMinimizer.minimize(QNMinimizer.java:923)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.QNMinimizer.minimize(QNMinimizer.java:885)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.QNMinimizer.minimize(QNMinimizer.java:879)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.QNMinimizer.minimize(QNMinimizer.java:91)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.trainWeights(CRFClassifier.java:1911)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.train(CRFClassifier.java:1718)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.train(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:759)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.train(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:747)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:2937)
```

Comment: I just trained one where 5g gave the same error, but 6g worked.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can try reducing number of classes is to not use B-I notation. For example, club B-facility and I-facility into facility. Of course, another way it to use a bigger memory machine.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be **-Xmx4g** not -mx4g?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for getting to this a bit late! I suspect the problem is the input format of the file; in particular, my first guess is that the file is being treated as a single long sentence.

The expected format of the training file is in the CoNLL format, which means each line of the file is a new token, and the end of a sentence is denoted by a double newline. So, for example, a file could look like:

```
Cats  O
have  O
tails  O
.  O

Felix  ANIMAL
is  O
a  O
cat  O
.  O
```

Could you let me know if it's indeed in this format? If so, could you include a stack trace of the error, and the properties file you are using? Does it work if you run on just the first few sentences of the file?

--Gabor

Comment: One dataset I am using to retrain is the twitter data from Alan Ritter's twitter nlp project : https://github.com/aritter/twitter_nlp/tree/master/data/annotated/ner.txt

Comment: When i do the retraining with just the company names annotated and every other word as O, then the retraining does not throw any errors or exceptions.(Basically, with reduced number of classes there are no memory issues)

Comment: I suspect Sonal is right, and the problem is the number of classes. I believe our NER is trained using simple classes, rather than the B-<class>, I-<class> format used by Alan. Then, L-BFGS seems to be running out of memory on the optimization problem with 21 (rather than 3 or 5) classes. 8x the classes means at least 8x the memory (> 8GB).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do analysis on non-transactional data sets you may want to use another tool like Elasticsearch (simpler) or Hadoop (exponentially more complicated).  MongoDB is a good middleground as well.

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the existing java jdk and reinstall again.
Then you can use the heap size as much as you can based on your hard disk size.
In the term "-mx4g" 4g is not the RAM it is the heap size.
Even I Faced the same error initially. after doing this it is gone.
Even I misunderstood 4g as RAM initially.

Now I am able to start my server even with 100g of heap size.

Next,
Instead of using Customised NER model, I suggest you to use Custom RegexNER Model with which you can add millions of words of same entity name within in a single document too.
These 2 errors I faced initially.

For any queries comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try to Reduce the Number of Threads as each Thread takes a lot of memory `multiThreadGrad=4` put this in your Properties File , play around with the number the lower the number of thread the slower the training process will be but you will most likely be able to train with your desired labels.